# AttributeError: module 'aiogram.types' has no attribute 'ChatNotFound'

Tags: python, aiogram

хотел написать команду userid, но возникла ошибка
Вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['userid'])
async def get_user_id(message: types.Message):
    try:
        user_mention = message.get_args()
        if not user_mention:
            await message.reply("Пожалуйста, укажите упоминание пользователя.")
            return

        user = await bot.get_chat(user_mention)
        user_id = user.id
        await message.reply(f"ID пользователя {user_mention}: {user_id}")
    except types.ChatNotFound:
        await message.reply("Пользователь не найден.")
```

Comment: Исключение `ChatNotFound` находится в `aiogram.utils.exceptions.ChatNotFound`.

Answer (score 1):

Как я уже написал в комментариях, исключение `ChatNotFound` находится в `aiogram.utils.exceptions.ChatNotFound`, соответственно, вам нужно изменить код так:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['userid'])
async def get_user_id(message: types.Message):
    try:
        ...
    except utils.exceptions.ChatNotFound:
    #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        await message.reply("Пользователь не найден.")
```

Также надо добавить нужный импорт в начало файла:

```py
from aiogram import utils
```